# How to stop touchesMoved

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I want win my frame moved 40/3px then stop moved!
How to stop moved and change frame x to 40+320! thank you

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(self.frame.origin.x > 40/3) {
            CGRect myFrame = self.frame; 
            myFrame.origin.x = 40 + self.frame.size.width;
            self.frame = myFrame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code like this :

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(self.frame.origin.x > 40/3) {
            CGRect myFrame = self.frame; 
            myFrame.origin.x = 40 + self.frame.size.width;
            self.frame = myFrame;
            [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps